# Should I use multiple variables or one dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to Python and see a lot of source codes using separate variables for things such as x and y coordinates or min and max values.

ex.

```
COORD_X = 45  
COORD_Y = 65  
SIZE_MIN = 1  
SIZE_MAX = 10
```

I was wondering why people didn't use dictionaries instead? And if I should follow their lead or do what feels better to me?

ex.

```
COORDS = {'x': 45, 'y': 65}  
SIZE = {'min': 1, 'max': 10}
```

Is it a performance issue or am I missing something?  Dictionaries seem like the better choice, especially if you have a lot of these sets of variable.  It cuts your variables in half and you only need to pass one variable to functions instead of two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many cases, it just comes down to personal style preferences. However, note that you're creating more objects to hold objects, which consumes more memory and has the performance hit of creation, as well as slightly slower lookup, so there would be instances (lots of objects, long running nested loops etc) where just having the multiple bindings would be benefitial.

For your examples, I'd probably use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). The example there is pretty much your `COORDS` instance:

```
 >>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'], verbose=True)
 >>> p = Point(11, y=22)
 >>> p.x + p.y
 33
```

Comment: I would object to even bothering to consider the memory and creation cost without knowing the context.  As someone who has spent time optimizing Python code, with the exception of functions that get run a ton, optimizing the data structures for small dicts and objects is almost irrelevant.  Python is much better suited for high-level optimization (i.e., caching, pushing processing to high-performance native libraries like numpy).  If you're hitting memory bounds from coordinates, you've got bigger issues than not using a tuple.

Comment: But named tuples are still great, and a great solution for coordinates.  Just need to be highly wary of premature low-level optimization in Python.

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing in all caps, it usually denotes that that variable is a constant. This means that it is better you keep it that way. In your case, creating a dictionary for two key:value pairs is overkill. Dictionaries should be used for longer pairs.

If you are keen on using a dictionary in this case, the following would be a better approach:

```
CONSTANTS = {'COORD_X': 45, 'COORD_Y': 65, 'SIZE_MIN': 1, 'SIZE_MAX': 10}
```

Then you can do things like:

```
>>> CONSTANTS['COORD_X']
45

>>> print CONSTANTS.keys()
('COORD_X', 'COORD_Y', 'SIZE_MIN', 'SIZE_MAX')
```

Comment: I find using a module for constants to be much more convenient: attribute lookup rather than field, inspectable with `dir(<module_name>)` and shareable across other files via `import`.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor, That is a good way, I agree. I was just using dictionaries since the OP mentioned those in his question. You should include your suggestion in your question. It would supplement it well.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary, it decreases readability, and it is just another layer of abstraction for your variables. You want to set `COORD_X=5` and `COORD_Y=10`. So you set it. Everyone expects you to set it. There is no reason to set

```
COORDS={'x':5, 'y':10}
```

Also, think about your function call comment, it narrows your functions a ton. Imagine a function this simple

```
def show_args(*args):
    print args
```

Now I want to show all my coords, you can't just pass this one your dictionary and go, it'll be different, you still have to pass each `COORDS[key]`. The only way I see it actually making it so you only have to pass one variable (the dictionary name) would be if you hard coded your functions

```
def show_args(varDict):
    print varDict['x'], varDict['y']
```

then you'd have to write one for each variable and also rewrite parts of that function every time you added a variable. You could loop over all the keys, but say you didn't want to print every single one? Still kinda sketchy.

> > It cuts your variables in half

No it doesn't, it adds more. Instead of `COORD_X` and `COORD_Y` you have the dictionary containing them and then their keys :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that this answer should also take in consideration the end purpose of your variables. I've found that dictionaries, despite the performance hit, can lead to more concise code if used wisely.

For example:
Let's suppose you are using python to handle JSONP, for which you have a return of this type:

```
return 'jsonCallback(' + json.dumps([{'results': results}]) + ');'
```

*results* could be a string such as 'deliverable' but what if you need to pass more data to the jsonCallback **but** that data is not always defined in all cases. Adding another variable will result in adding another independent variable to the return value, such as:

```
return 'jsonCallback(' + json.dumps([{'results': results, 'sometimes': data}]) + ');'
```

In the this case, `'sometimes': data` will always have to be defined whereas using the dict collection for *results* variable leads to cleaner code since you would keep passing a single dict variable with variable content data.